# How to query many to many

Tags: php, sql, mysql, sql-server-2008, pdo

I'm trying to do a many to many query on these fields. I'd like to get:

1) all the posts that are in a category

2) all the categories that are in a post

3) all the posts that are in a category that have a specific id

```
    posts
+-------------+--------------+
| id          | int(11)      |
| title       | varchar(255) |
| body        | text         |
| parent_id   | int(11)      |
| category_id | int(11)      |
+-------------+--------------+
    post_categories 
+----------+--------------+
| id       | int(11)      |
| category | varchar(255) |
+----------+--------------+
    post_category_bridge
+-------------+-------------+
| id          | int(11)     |
| post_id     | int(11) |
| category_id | int(11) |
+-------------+-------------+
```

One thing I'm worried about is that I'm using PHP's PDO on a MySQL DB for development but I will be transferring the site to an SQL Server on launch day. I know there are differences between MySQL and SQL Server. Will POD take care of those differences or will I need to re-write these queries.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is do you have `post.id` as an `int(11)` but `post_category_bridge.post_id` as a `tinyint(11)`? Is this something common in creating foreign keys?

Comment: You don't need your category_id on the posts table.  That should be the purpose of your "bridge" or relationship table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm using the verbose join syntax to be more clear on how the tables are related.

**1) all the posts that are in a category**

Given the category name, you need to join all three tables.

```
select p.*
  from post_category c
    join post_category_bridge b on c.id = b.category_id
    join posts p                on p.id = b.post_id
  where c.category = ?
```

**2) all the categories that are in a post**

Given the post id, you only need to join the bridge and category tables.

```
select c.*
  from post_category_bridge b
    join post_category c        on c.id = b.category_id
  where b.post_id = ?
```

**3) all the posts that are in a category that have a specific id**

I think you mean looking up posts by `category.id` here (as opposed to `category.name`) which is similar to (1) but does not need to join on the category table, as you already know the id; you only need to join the bridge and post tables.

```
select p.*
  from post_category_bridge b
    join posts                  on p.id = b.post_id
  where b.category_id = ?
```

**I will be transferring the site to an SQL Server on launch day...Will POD take care of those differences or will I need to re-write these queries.**

This depends on the queries that end up in your system. If you're writing your own SQL then it will matter if you use features or syntax unique to MySQL during development. I highly recommend testing on SQL Server **Long before** launch day or you may find launch postponed for a while. You can download a free [evaluation version](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/trial-software.aspx) for just this purpose.

**Points mentioned in the comments that bear repeating:**

- as [@freddy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3137128#comment-3223049) mentions, you don't need the `posts.category_id` field. In many-to-many relationships, the bridge (aka 'junction', 'join', 'map', 'link', etc) table links posts to multiple categories - a single field on the `posts` table would be used if *only one* category were allowed.
- as [@JamieWong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3137128#comment-3222914) mentions, you should keep types consistent between table keys and foreign keys, e.g. if `posts.id` is `int(11)`, then `post_category_bridge.post_id` should also be `int(11)`. Most (all?) databases that enforce foreign key constraints will require this (including MySQL). Why? If a there can be 4294967295 posts (as supported by the 4 byte `int`) there's little point in a bridge table that only supports linking to 255 posts (as supported by the 1 byte `tinyint`)
- While your at it... might as well make the IDs (and FKs to those IDs) `unsigned`.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

1:

```
select p.* from posts p, post_categories c
where p.category_id=c.id and category='something'
```

2:

```
select c.* from post_categories, posts p
where p.category_id=c.id and post_id=something
```

3:

```
select p.* from post_categories, posts p
where p.category_id=c.id and post_id=something and category='something'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.*  from posts a, post_categories b, post_category_bridge c 
WHERE 
     b.category="mycat" AND 
     b.id=c.category_id AND 
     a.id = c.post_id;
```

```
select b.category from posts a, post_categories b, post_category_bridge c,
WHERE
    c.post_id='PostID' AND
    b.id = c.category_id;
```

```
select a.*  from posts a, post_categories b, post_category_bridge c 
WHERE 
     b.category="mycat" AND 
     c.category_id = b.id AND 
     c.post_id = 'MyID' AND
     a.id = c.post_id;
```